# too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 3 were indexed, what does indexed mean?

Tags: python, numpy

```
 c_scheme = p.pcolor(x, y, np.squeeze(xco2[0,:,:]), cmap = 'jet')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/welcome/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/ma/core.py", line 3224, in __getitem__
    dout = self.data[indx]
IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 3 were indexed
```

Comment: Clearly `xco2` is a 1d array - but you haven't shown the rest of the program to see the details. You are trying to do a 3-dimensional slice: `[0, :, :]`.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears to be a question about the English language, not about programming. Please try https://ell.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

It would help if I could see how xco2 is defined, but I'll try to answer anyway.

It seems that xco2 is an array created 1-dimensionally. This means the array is only indexed by (the value you are looking for is selected by) a single number. However, here, [0,:,:] is a 3-dimensional index, since there are three arguments in the brackets.

assuming p.pcolor() only needs a single variable out of xco2, you can completely remove np.squeeze, and simply use `c_scheme = p.pcolor(x, y, xco2[0], cmap = 'jet')`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [answer]. If you need more information to answer the question, you should ask for it in the comments, or (since you don't yet have the reputation score for that) wait for it to be cleared up. Don't guess at what the problem is. (Also, please note that we are trying to be a source of knowledge here and *not a discussion forum*, so comments like "hope that helps" are considered [noise](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions/260778#260778).)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, I don't see anything wrong with this answer.  Yes, it is similar to `alani's` comment, but I think the OP needs more information.  As you note the OP may have language problems.  In that case, this wordier answer might be more useful than a short answer.  They tell us to be nice to new questioners.  The same applies to new answers.

Comment: I am being nice. The observation about noise relates to text that @Dharman removed from the post. The issue stands: if the OP needs more information, then *every* answer is wrong by virtue of existing.